# Inserting values with a CASE statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to put some values in a `table`, specifically values that are decided by the `DML` operations that  I am using:
 - If I am `inserting` a row, I need to put that i am doing an `INSERT` into a table (that i am using for register all the operations that are made by the user
 - If i am `deleting`, then `DELETE`
 - and the same thing when I am `updating`.

My code is the following to `insert` those rows on my `table`:

```
INSERT INTO AUD(usr, date, op, other_fields)
VALUES
(USER, SYSDATE,
CASE op
    WHEN INSERTING THEN 'INSERT'
    WHEN DELETING THEN 'DELETE'
    WHEN UPDATING THEN 'UPDATE'
END,
:OLD.other_fields
:NEW.other_fields);
```

But when I am using this in my trigger and I compile it, it shows me an `ORA-00084` error and ignores some previous lines of my trigger. Thanks in advance

I tried with `DECODE` too, but it shows me the same error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
   ...
   l_op aud.op%type;    
begin
  ...
  if INSERTING then
    l_op := 'INSERT';
  ...
  elsif UPDATING then
    l_op := 'UPDATE';
  ...
  end if;

  ...
  if l_op in ('INSERT', 'DELETE') 
     or l_op = 'UPDATE' 
        and (nvl(:old.fied1, 0) != nvl(:new.fied1, 0)
             or nvl(:old.fied2, 0) != nvl(:new.fied2, 0)
             ...
            )
  then 
    INSERT INTO AUD(usr, date, op, other_fields)
    values (USER, SYSDATE, l_op, :OLD.other_fields, :NEW.other_fields);
  end if;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I applied it and it shows that UPDATING identifier is not valid, when it must not say that, because it's a condition.

Comment: @Ryuuko Matoi You can't use trigger predicates (INSERTING, UPDATING, DELETING) in expressions (only in special such as IF INSERTING THEN ... END IF;)

Comment: That's sad. And if I want to use it into my insert (it is place into a trigger), how can I use those predicates? there's another alternative?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine. But if I don't want to register the :new changes unless the :old has been changed, what I can do in that case?

Comment: @Ryuuko Matoi You can use IF outside the INSERT. I've updated my answer.